Where to put the restic repository password?
I'm using restic to back up a volume of mine to a cloud storage.
I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to automate restic.
restic needs the repository password somehow. Where to put it?
At the moment I'm using the following mechanism:

Password is in a file that is encrypted with DPAPI
Nobody else than Administrators have access to the file
My user is an Administrator, but does not have the high-privilege token all the time
Task in task scheduler runs with high-privilege access rights to gain access to the files

This sounds like glorified security-through-obfuscation though. Do I have any better options?
